# Objective C: constantly calling a function

Tags: objective-c, date, time, counter

I'm trying to make a pretty simple game and I'm stuck. Basically I want to make a UIImageView appear every 2 seconds. My problem is I can't keep track of cumulative time. Right now I have this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval secondsSinceNow = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];

NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
NSLog(@"secondsSinceNow = %f", secondsSinceNow);
```

It's in my button function so its called when the user taps the button. It returns a decimal number always less than 1. I've tried it in the viewDidLoad method as well as it's own method but neither work.

I think it would work if its in it's own method that is check constantly, but I don't know how to do that.

In short, I need a timer/counter that updates every second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@interface className
{
NSTimer * timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer * timer;

@end


@implementation className
@synthesize timer;

...
```

/*factory method was corrected here. should work without warnings by copying and pasting */

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching : (UIApplication *) application {
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

}

//define the target method
```

/*method was corrected because it needed parentheses around NSTimer */

```
-(void) targetMethod: (NSTimer *) theTimer {
NSLog(@"Me is here at 1 minute delay");
}
..
@end
```

taken from here
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/14403-nstimer-examples.html

Comment: The name of the factory method is wrong, the right factory method is called scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to call a selector within your class at the required two second interval.

That said, you could possibly also make use of a [CABasicAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to fade the opacity of the UIImageView, pending on the effect you require.

Answer (score 0):

If those first two lines are called immediately after each other, then it (should) always be less than a second. The date is being instantiated right there, and then the timeIntervalSinceNow is called immediately on it, when little/no time has occured between them. The goal is to make the date when first called, and then call the timeIntervalSinceNow on that to get times more than 0. However, this still has no creation of a updating timer as you want.